# existence of an elliptic curves with given number of points over finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, finite-fields, computational-number-theory

Is there a theorem which guarentees the existance of an elliptic curve with given number of points over $\mathbf{F}_p$ for a given $p$.

Thanks

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317531/deurings-result-on-elliptic-curves-any-proof-reference, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87916

Answer (score 10):

Deuring proved that for every $a, |a| < 2\sqrt{p}$, there exists an elliptic curve with $p+1-a$ points over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

M Deuring, Die Typen der Multiplikatorenringe elliptischer Funktionenkörper, Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg 14 (1941), 197-272.

Comment: Do we have any way to construct such an elliptic curve   in polynomial in $logp$ steps or can anyone tell about algorithms on constructing them.

Comment: That's a different question, and people are unlikely to spot it here as a comment on an answer. You should ask a different question.

Comment: @HimanshuShukla Deuring's proof developed into what's known as the CM method of constructing elliptic curves. I believe the construction is polynomial in $D{\log p}$ steps where $D = 4p - a^2$.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch can you please give me a link of the paper by Deuring

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are looking for Honda-Tate theory, see http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1260463295 Honda, Taira (1968), "Isogeny classes of abelian varieties over finite fields", Journal of the Mathematical Society of Japan, 20: 83–95. (The eigenvalues of the Frobenius determine the number of $\mathbf{F}_{q^n}$-rational points by the Lefschetz trace formula.)