# Deuring's result on elliptic curves. Any proof reference

Tags: reference-request, alternative-proof, elliptic-curves

I have heard of this result from Deuring 1941 paper: Given $\mathbb F_p$ ($p$ prime number) and any number $n$ in the Hasse interval $[p+1-2\sqrt p, p+1+2\sqrt p]$ there is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$ having $n$ points. I have minimal knowledge on more advanced topics on elliptic curves (only know a thing or two on isogenies and the endomorphism ring and enough algebraic geometry that can get me through the proofs). So I wanted to know if there is an easy proof of this result. I looked at the original Deuring's paper (German) and the 78 page paper, at first sight, it does not immediately tell me where I can find this statement (I am sure it is hidden in some context in the paper). So I ask, if someone could kindly point to me:

1. The location on the paper where the above statement immediately follows (I hope I do not need to read the whole paper for that)
2. Is there any modern (perhaps english) treatment of Deuring's proof? or at least a simplified one where I do not really need to look at elliptic curves over number fields (aside from $\mathbb Q$) to understand the proof of the statement (at the moment I am only concerned with the simplest case, i.e. elliptic curves over finite fields with prime order).

I tried to look at Lang's book "Elliptic Functions", but I think he does not prove this result. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Edit**: It seems I will have no luck here. There is a not so unrelated post asking a similar question: [Proof or Translation of Deuring's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517425/proof-or-translation-of-deurings-theorem)

Comment: This is Theorem 14.18 in Cox, Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$.

Comment: Sorry I missed this comment (the comment came 2 years after my original post). Exactly which book of Cox (and which Cox) do you refer to?

Comment: Sorry, David Cox, [Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$](https://www.amazon.com/Primes-Form-x2-ny2-Multiplication/dp/1118390180/ref=sr_1_5?crid=1BV2FW3H166S&dchild=1&keywords=david+cox+prime&qid=1612812838&sprefix=cox+primes%2Caps%2C197&sr=8-5)

Comment: Oh sorry, you already mentioned the title (I was a bit surprised because I did not know David Cox worked on this topic). I scanned thru it very fast and see that it relies on Thereom 13.21 which is on the splitting of the prime $p$  in a number field. This Theorem then refers to Deuring (or Lang) for the proof. With reference to Lang I think I can follow the proof without looking at Deuring. You should post this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find the following paper useful, although it proves something more general than what you are asking:

[MR0890272](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=890272),
Rück, Hans-Georg,
A note on elliptic curves over finite fields.
*Math. Comp*. **49** (1987), no. 179, 301–304,
doi:[10.1090/S0025-5718-1987-0890272-3](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1987-0890272-3).

There is also the paper:

[MR0265369](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=265369),
Waterhouse, William C.,
Abelian varieties over finite fields.
*Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup*. (4) **2** 1969 521–560,
doi:[10.24033/asens.1183](https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1183).

The [review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=265369) of this second paper says: "In Chapter 4, Deuring's results on elliptic curves are derived, where the classification is very explicit."

Answer (score 3):

Theorem 14.18 in Cox, *Primes of the form $^2+ n y^2$* (AMS, 2022, doi:[10.1090/chel/387](https://doi.org/10.1090/chel/387)) contains a proof of this fact. It does rely on a theorem proved both in Deuring's paper and in Lang's *Elliptic Functions*, Graduate Texts in Mathematics **112** (1987) doi:[10.1007/978-1-4612-4752-4](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-4752-4).