# quadratic residues and cubic polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

I'm really not sure about this, but I've heard somewhere that for any prime $p$,
$|\sum_{x=0}^{p-1} (\frac{ax^3 +bx^2 +cx +d}{p} ) |\le \sqrt{2p}$ holds.
Does anyone know a proof for this inequality or a similar result?

Comment: It should be $2\sqrt{p}$. This is [Hasse's theorem on elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves).

Comment: At least for $a\neq 0$... For $a=c=d=0$, $b=1$, it is obviously false!

Comment: Wow thanks!! That was what I was looking for

Comment: A nice self-contained proof is given in Voloch's answer to  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87916.